# docker rmi cannot remove images, with: no such id

Tags: docker

I have a lot of images. When I try to remove them with `docker rmi`

```
$ sudo docker rmi acd33a9490dc
Error response from daemon: No such id: 75ce1f6710bab109a7d7cbee056fa8a0c7fa913e81c88e2a55121149dda80ee9
2014/07/14 10:13:24 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

That 75ce1... hash is the same no matter which docker image I try to remove.

At present, the below gives the current docker version; however some of these images have been around since an earlier version (0.6 or so)

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bug report. Not an actual question.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you attempt to remove by repository name:tag instead of image ID?

Comment: please list more detail information like `docker images --tree`,`docker images -a`, `docker ps -a`, may need to check `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` to see what this id really has

Comment: was this solved? i have the same problem.

Comment: no. I have various other workarounds going on that makes this less necessary to need to be able to do.

Comment: irc freenode.net/#docker or github.com/dotcloud/docker would be better places for this kind of question.

Answer (score 70):

Put in your terminal:

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID | IMAGE ......................NAMES

d25c0cd9725a |acd33a9490dc ................focused_einstein
```

You can see your IMAGEID in the column IMAGE. Get the CONTAINER ID an remove the container:

```
docker rm d25c0cd9725a
```

And now you can remove the image:

```
docker rmi acd33a9490dc
```

Comment: If you're wanting to remove *all* of them, this is a good shortcut: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

Comment: Similarly, therefore, you can use `docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)` to delete all images (after you've removed their corresponding containers)

Answer (score 19):

If you need to remove several images, then you can delete all containers with

```
sudo docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -I {} sudo docker rm {}
```

Now you can remove any images.

Comment: Using boot2docker in Git bash I had to run: "docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 docker rm"

Comment: On OSX, from my Vagrant SSH, I needed to first do : " sudo docker ps -a -q | xargs -n 1 -I {}  sudo docker stop {}". After that, the above remove command worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I think this is the expected behavior, not a bug. This is because you have containers hanging around that have not been deleted. These containers are instances of the image, and that is preventing you from dropping that image.

#### Step 1 - remove unused container instances

Both [jripoll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958788/734790) and [Andras Hatvani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488450/734790) show ways of listing and removing the containers that are bound to the images.

***Note that the latter will delete all container instances!!*** So, if there is one that you need to commit as a new image, you should [do that first](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images).

#### Step 2 - remove unnecessary images

After the containers have been deleted, you will be able to remove any images they were based on.

To quickly remove any untagged containers *(ones that show up as `<none> <none>` when you run `sudo docker images`)* you can run the following command:

```
    sudo docker images -q --filter "dangling=true" | sudo xargs docker rmi
```

I have saved that in `/usr/local/bin/docker-purge-dangling` so I can run it without needing to remember the command.

Comment: I was getting this error: "Error response from daemon: No such id: 75ce1f6710bab109a7d7cbee056fa8a0c7fa913e81c88e2a55121149dda80ee9" with that specific ID no matter which image I tried to remove. I don't see how that would be because every image was tied to an existing container.

Comment: @BenClifford Yeah, I had the same problem when trying to remove the image. I had 4 images that had no tags that I had tried to drop. Dropping the container instances then allowed me to finally remove them.

Answer (score 11):

You may also face this issue if you do not remove exited containers.
You need to remove the exited container by doing this,

```
sudo docker ps -a | grep Exit | awk '{print $1}' | sudo xargs docker rm
```

Then remove your image using

```
sudo docker rmi <imageID>
```

Answer (score 10):

First you need to locate the container holding the image.

**To remove a single container with the image**

```
docker ps -a
```

You will get such an output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
g7aea2132441        2285ff53ab18        "/bin/bash"         2 days ago                                                  tombrider
```

Then remove the container using

```
docker rm g7aea2132441
```

**To remove all the containers and images do**

1. Remove all the containers

   ```
   docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
   docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
   ```
2. Remove the now dangling images

   ```
   docker images -q --filter "dangling=true" | sudo xargs docker rmi
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Sincere appreciation to all of you.
I have tried all your approaches, but was not able to delete the following image:

```
[myself@testvm]$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
hello-world   latest  c54a2cc56cbb  6 months ago  1.848 kB
```

I had to remove it from here instead:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/image/devicemapper/imagedb/content/sha256/c54a2cc56cbb2f04003c1cd4507e118af7c0d340fe7e2720f70976c4b75237dc
```

Now it is gone.

Comment: i had the same issue with an image with the same name&size. i don't know how this image was created. i did it for sure, but same name, size, issue :D funny

Comment: I've had this issue as well, docker's data directory can become corrupt. I wouldn't recommend point deletion unless you know what you're doing, instead stopping docker, empty the folder (move its contents to backup), reinstall and restart docker. This is problematic though if you don't want to lose anything, but is the best way to ensure you maintain integrity. I'm wondering if this can happen if you update docker or something is stopped midway, for me the image was a couple of years old and refused to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. My colleague uploaded docker and apparently, he updated it in such a way that dangling images from the older version of docker were not deleted, when the newer version was installed. So after the update, after killing all running containers and then removing all images with the `rmi` command, the images from the older version were still there! Deleting the image files with the `rm` command actually did solve the problem for me. All the other answers didn't really solve the OP's problem, so this answer definitely deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 3):

Running this cleanup script I made somehow magically solves this for me:

```
# remove orphan containers
docker ps -a | grep -v ":" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm -f

# remove orphan images
docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Answer (score 1):

So... some cases of this seem to be because you have a no-longer-running container that references the image. Removing the container allows you to then remove the image.

But there is definitely a bug where docker gets itself into a state where no matter what you do, it can't remove *any* image. This has been fixed in docker 1.4.0: https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/ac40e7c

Answer (score 0):

this will remove all your container and then you can remove the images

sudo docker ps -a | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v CONTAINER | xargs sudo docker rm {}\;