# docker cannot remove images?

Tags: storage, docker, boot2docker

```
 docker images
```

lists

test  latest e10eb3d3a067        **7 days ago**          1.094 GB

But i tried to remove it using

```
  docker rmi e10eb3d3a067

  docker rmi -f <same_id>
```

It says, `No such id :<different id, not the one i provided> and Error: failed to remove`

Any suggestions to remove it?

I reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733160/docker-rmi-cannot-remove-images-with-no-such-id) But i don't have any running contianers and no dependency between images that i want to remove.

Comment: If you want to remove ALL your containers, do `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` and then remove all your images with `docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)`

Comment: @user2915097 i don't want to remove all. i want to remove about 90%, most of the images are created 3days back

Comment: @GopsAB try removing all *stopped* containers (see docker ps -a) first then try again.

Comment: same logic, check with `docker ps -a`, find the ones you want to get rid, and do for them `docker rmi -f id`

Comment: Thats what i am saying it is not working.

Comment: Might be the same issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3258

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the below command to list down all the containers

   `docker ps -a --format="container:{{.ID}} image:{{.Image}}"`
2. Try to remove the image which you want

   `sudo docker rmi <image-id>`
3. If you still get the same error then try to remove the containers associated with that image.

   `sudo docker rm <container-id>`
4. Now try to remove the image